# Send UILabels and UIImage to real apple watch from Iphone in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uilabel, apple-watch

I want to send `UILabels` and `UIImage` data to my watch app from ios app.  I am getting it in simulator when i click "sendtowatch" button. But when i run it in real devices, only the label is shown not the image.

Source code for **watch:**

```
    class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController, WCSessionDelegate {

    var session: WCSession!

    var MessageData = NSMutableDictionary()

    @IBOutlet var watch_displayImage: WKInterfaceImage!
    @IBOutlet var watch_ticket_category: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet var watch_ticketType: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet var watch_ticketTime: WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet var watch_ticketDate: WKInterfaceLabel!

    override func awakeWithContext(context: AnyObject?) {
        super.awakeWithContext(context)

        if WCSession.isSupported()
        {

            session = WCSession.defaultSession()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activateSession()

        }

    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()


    }


    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : AnyObject]) -> Void)
    {

        print(message.values)

        MessageData = NSMutableDictionary(object: message, forKey: "data")
        print("Message data---",MessageData)

        watch_ticket_category.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["ticket_category"] as! String)")
        watch_displayImage.setImage(UIImage(named: MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["imagePath"] as! String))
        watch_ticketType.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["ticket_type"] as! String)")
        watch_ticketTime.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["time"] as! String)")
        watch_ticketDate.setText("\(MessageData["data"]!["Watchdat"]!!["date"] as! String)")


   }
```

Source code for **IOS app:**

```
   class TicketDetailViewController: UIViewController, WCSessionDelegate {
  let dic1  = NSMutableDictionary()
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults()
    var databasePath = NSString()
    var holding_Ticket_category: String = ""
    var holding_Image: UIImage?
    var hold_ticketName: String = ""
    var hold_ticketDate: String = ""
    var hold_ticketTime: String = ""
    var session: WCSession!
    var imageData: NSData!

    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_grey: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var cropped_frame: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var display_image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_type_name: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_date: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_time: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ticket_category: UILabel!


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if WCSession.isSupported(){
            self.session  = WCSession.defaultSession()
            self.session.delegate = self
            self.session.activateSession()
        }

        defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        display_image.image = self.holding_Image
        ticket_type_name.text = hold_ticketName
        ticket_date.text = hold_ticketDate
        ticket_time.text = hold_ticketTime
        ticket_category.text = holding_Ticket_category

        let filemgr =  NSFileManager.defaultManager()
        let dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let docsDir = dirPaths[0]
        var ticketDB: FMDatabase

        databasePath = (docsDir as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent("ticket_Pass.sqlite")


        if !filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(databasePath as String)
        {

            ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
            if ticketDB.open()
            {

                let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TICKET (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMAGEPATH TEXT, IMAGENAME TEXT, TICKET_CATEGORY TEXT, TICKET_TYPE TEXT, DATE TEXT, TIME TEXT)"
                if !ticketDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)
                {
                    print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }
                ticketDB.close()
            } else
            {
                 print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }
        }else{
            ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
            if ticketDB.open()
            {

                let sql_stmt = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TICKET (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, IMAGEPATH TEXT, IMAGENAME TEXT, TICKET_CATEGORY TEXT, TICKET_TYPE TEXT, DATE TEXT, TIME TEXT)"
                if !ticketDB.executeStatements(sql_stmt)
                {
                    print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
                }
                ticketDB.close()
            } else
            {

                print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")
            }

        }
    }

    func saveImageToFolder()
    {

        imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(holding_Image!)!
        let imageName = "image_\(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate()).png"
        let imagePath = (self.getDocumentsDirectory() as NSString).stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
        print("imagePath:- \(imagePath)")

        imageData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imagePath, forKey: "ImagePath")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imageData, forKey: "ImageData")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(imageName, forKey: "ImageName")
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    }

    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> String{
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        let documentsPath = paths[0]
        print("document path:- \(documentsPath)")
        return documentsPath

    }

  @IBAction func addTickets(sender: UIButton)
  {

        let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if ticketDB.open()
        {
                //self.saveImageToFolder()
                let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO TICKET (imagePath, imageName, ticket_category, ticket_type, date, time) VALUES ('\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImagePath")!)', '\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImageName")!)', '\(ticket_category.text!)', '\(ticket_type_name.text!)', '\(ticket_date.text!)', '\(ticket_time.text!)')"

                let result = ticketDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)

                if !result
                {

                    print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

                } else
                {

                    let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Success!", description: "Your data is saved to Database!", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

                    alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .Default, action: { (ACTION) -> Void in

                    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)

                    }))

                    self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    print(databasePath)

               }
        }
    }


    @IBAction func deleteTickets(sender: UIButton) {
        let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Delete Ticket Details!", description: "Are you sure?", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

        alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: PMAlertActionStyle.Default, action: { (ACTION) -> Void in

            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

        }))
        alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK", style: PMAlertActionStyle.Default, action: { (ACTION) -> Void in

            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }))
        self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    @IBAction func sendToWatch(sender: AnyObject)
    {

        let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
        if ticketDB.open()
        {
            self.saveImageToFolder()
            let insertSQL = "INSERT INTO TICKET (imagePath, imageName, ticket_category, ticket_type, date, time) VALUES ('\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImagePath")!)', '\(NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ImageName")!)', '\(ticket_category.text!)', '\(ticket_type_name.text!)', '\(ticket_date.text!)', '\(ticket_time.text!)')"

            let result = ticketDB.executeUpdate(insertSQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)

            if !result
            {

                print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

            } else
            {

                let alt = PMAlertController(title: "Success!", description: "Your data is saved!", image: UIImage(named: ""), style: .Alert)

                alt.addAction(PMAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: .Default, action:
                { (ACTION) -> Void in


                        let ticketDB = FMDatabase(path: self.databasePath as String)
                        if ticketDB.open()
                        {

//                            let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM TICKET ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1"
                             let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM TICKET "

                            let result: FMResultSet? = ticketDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)

                            if let result = result
                            {

                                let ticketDataArray:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
                                while result.next()
                                {

                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("imagePath"), forKey: "imagePath")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("imageName"), forKey: "imageName")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("ticket_category"), forKey: "ticket_category")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("ticket_type"), forKey: "ticket_type")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("date"), forKey: "date")
                                    self.dic1.setObject(result.stringForColumn("time"), forKey: "time")

                                    ticketDataArray.addObject(self.dic1)

                                }
                                print("ticketDataArray :  \(self.dic1)")
                            }else
                            {
                                print("Error: \(ticketDB.lastErrorMessage())")

                            }

                          ticketDB.close()

                        }
                    self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true)
                        if WCSession.defaultSession().reachable
                        {
                            let dict = ["Watchdat":self.dic1]

                            self.session.sendMessage(dict, replyHandler: { (replayDic: [String:AnyObject]) in
                                print("success!")
                                }, errorHandler: { (error:NSError) in
                                    print("error")
                            })
                        }

                }))

                self.presentViewController(alt, animated: true, completion: nil)
                print(databasePath)

            }
        }
```

Comment: thank you dipen panchasara and carlo

Comment: am i somewhere wrong in my code?

Comment: can someone help me out with my problem stated

Comment: or is it because of the image size i am sending to apple watch.